# Create a single which contains string and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have one list

```
list1 = [['abc'], 'xyz', 'jhg', ['uvw', 'cde']]
```

with this list1 we need to create another list as shown below

```
list1 = ['abc', 'xyz', 'jhg', 'uvw', 'cde']
```

I am new in python please help

Comment: It's called 'flattening', which you can look up

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple looping logic can do the trick:

```
final_list = []
for item in list1:
     if type(item)==list:
          final_list += item
     else:
          final_list.append(item)
```